# how to count elements in values and replace it with the number of elements

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to count elements in a value and replace it with the number of elements in a dataframe

for example...
I want to change this

```
          'equips'  
0     shoes, balls, bags
1        shoes, bags
2           balls
3          rockets
4        bags, shoes 
5  bags, shoes, balls, rockets
6            NaN
```

into this

```
       'equips'  
0         3
1         2  
2         1
3         1
4         2 
5         4
6         0
```

But I don't know how to do that...

looking forward to finding an answer here!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.alphabets = df.alphabets.map(len)` should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! But I want to change them regardless of their length..!! Is their any other way?? I just took alphabets as an example, but elements that I have are quite longer...

Comment: @Seong-ho I am afraid I do not understand what you are trying to do, then.

Comment: ah... I got it I was the one who were confused..! Thank you for the answer!!

Comment: @Seong-ho my answer will still work, except for the NaN, though you can preface my answer by `df.alphabets.fillna(value=[], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Put the Elements from alphabets in a List of Char. Or alternative use a HashMap in Java. Key should be the 0,1,2,3. Value a List of Char. Then if this HashMap is generated use HashMap.keySet() to get all keys. "Foreach" them and get the Lenght of the current List of Char.